# Overloaded method error in Scala Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, compiler-errors, playframework-2.0

I am writing a method to set the session cookie properly after a user authenticates. Setting the cookies as follows does not work. The following snippet results in an error with the 'withSession' call:

**Overloaded method value [withSession] cannot be applied to ((String, Long))**

Code:

```
/**
 * Process login form submission.
 */
def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
  loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.login(formWithErrors)),
    credentials => {
      val user = models.User.findByEmail(credentials._1)

      user match {
        case Some(u) => {
          Redirect(routes.Dashboard.index).withSession(Security.username -> u.id)
        }
        case None => Redirect(routes.Auth.login)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

'credentials' is simply a tuple with the email and password submitted by the user. If I get rid of 'withSession' part then it runs fine. If I move the 'Redirect' statement out of the pattern matching code then is works fine. Why does it not work as I have it above and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think withSession expects a String, String

Have a look at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.SimpleResult

```
def withSession(session: (String, String)*): PlainResult = withSession(Session(session.toMap))
```